# How to truns my Spring 4 app to a aouth2 server provider like Gmail login?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm working on spring 4 mvc web app, and I want to turns my app to oauth2 server provider, in other words, I want the app to be a social network that can be logged in with in other websites, when the other website user tries to log in they offer him an option to login with my app and redirect him to my app (the user is already registered on my app) and ask him to allow sharing his data

any help where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of reading and researching, I made it!
and here are some useful links:

O-Auth2 Protocol : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Spring implementation for O-Auth : https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/implementing-oauth2-with-spring-security/

any Qs just leave a comment ;)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: unfortunately, I cant just quote or summaries
the idea here is to help others find a good way to start implementing  similar requirements